# limit the record displayed in a view using hook_views_query_alter

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

i want to change the number of items returned by a view. I changed the code as

```
$view->set_items_per_page(2);
```

in hook_views_query_alter();
But it is not showing the required result. But there is color difference after 2 records. Is it required any other settings I put my pager as off in view.
ie Use Pager:off . I want to use this on draggable view table. Is it possible?
Pls help me
[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are only altering the query programmatically and view exist then

1] Go to your **view basic settings** and click on **item to display**

```
  bottom of your view you will get the 2 text boxes.
```

2] In first text box put the number you want, in your case put 2 and leave second text box 0. and hit the **update default display** button and save your view.

Comment: I have to do this programmatically.

Comment: if you are creating view completely through programming then this link might help you http://drupal.org/node/409808

Comment: This link didn't provide any information to limit the record displayed by the view. I am already created one view programmatically and it works well. Now i only want to limit the records displayed.